# Import comma delimited numerical data from web

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I use the Import Data --> from web in Excel 2007 to import data from a website. It looks like this on web:

```
000002678,000002737,000002827,000004326,000008528
```

But as soon as I import it into Excel, it transforms to following:

```
2,678,000,002,737,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
```

How can I maintain the format as it is on web and not treat it as one big number?

I don't see any option to mention my numbers are comma delimited when when importing from a website (URL).

Comment: If you follow the instructions in the answer but substitute "comma" instead of "tab" you'll get what you want.

Comment: @Nifle There is no option to substitute "Comma" instead of "tab" when you import data from web using "querytables.add" The instructions are for importing a text file, not through a website using "querytables.add"

Comment: Question reopened, but next time maybe consider being more explicit about what exactly you've tried and why that didn't work for you (e.g. that there's no option to set comma as delimiter). That should make the difference more obvious.

Comment: So far have not found a way to do this using the QueryTables functionality (i.e., using different combinations of the properties that can be set, via either the user interface or editing the iqy file directly). Copying the HTML page into the sheet or opening a locally-saved copy of the HTML page as an Excel file produces the same unwanted result. I suspect that what will be required is a VBA routine to pull the HTML in and then parse the HTML to pick out the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Try (temporarily) turning off system separators (Excel Options > Advanced > Editing options, uncheck Use system separators, OK).

Comment: Still the same output

Comment: Yes, I tried in an empty workbook. Cleared the thousand and decimal separators. Tried it with the check-box checked and unchecked. Does it work when you try?

Comment: Yes, I clicked OK. I think copy paste works but importing from web doesnt